# Code igniter set_messages/set_errors_delimiters in config files

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, config

I have a file form_validation.php in application/config/form_validation.php which content :

```
$config = array(

        'inscription' => array(
                array(
                    'field' => 'nom',
                    etc ..
```

How can I add errors delimiters or messages like

```
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="erreur-inscription">', '</p>');           ) 
$this->form_validation->set_message('matches', 'Erreur lors de la confirmation du mot de passe');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a Base controller

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
 function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="erreur-inscription">', '</p>');           ) 
    $this->form_validation->set_message('matches', 'Erreur lors de la confirmation du mot de passe');
 }
}
```

and then extend this for other controller

```
class Main_Controller extends MY_Controller
 {
  function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
    // do some session stuff here :)
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Put this code in your `Form_validation` file:

```
$config['error_prefix']= '<div class="test-danger">';
$config['error_sufix]=  '</div>';
```